# Wordpress On subfolder

Tags: htaccess, installation, customization

We are running WordPress and CodeIgniter in the same domain, separated by subfolders. We know it's not the best practice, but CodeIgniter will be a temporary thing until we fully move to WordPress.

I was wondering if anybody could help me with an `.htaccess` file to allow WordPress and CodeIgniter to run without clashing with each other.

For some reason WordPress configuration is taking over the entire site.

```
public_html/
 .htaccess (blank)
 /wordpress/
 /codeigniter/
```

To access WordPress, we use `domain.com` and to use CodeIgniter we use `domain.com/codeigniter`. Everything works fine but CodeIgniter keeps redirecting to the WordPress site.

.htaccess

@PatJ Hello - yes i've copy .htaccess in both directories public_html/ and wordpress/

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in your `/wordpress/` directory? How do you have it set up that accessing `domain.com` loads the WordPress site?

Comment: @PatJ Hello - yes i've copy .htaccess in both directories public_html/ and wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like this..

`.htaccess` on your root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`.htaccess` inside your `/wordpress/` directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`.htaccess` in your `/codeigniter/` directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /codeigniter/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.htaccess` rules are cascading from the level they are defined on downwards. So in this case whatever rules you have in root apply to both subfolders.

You need:

1. Only rules that affect whole site in root
2. Any WordPress rules in subfolder it's in
3. And same for CodeIgniter